# Appstore Policy: Why do apps stop using appstore and instead install from web sites?

Tags: mac-appstore

Today I've seen this message from SourceTree app (gui repo-manager):
'You have a behind version that supported now. We move from appstore and you need to download application from link below.'

Why did they abandon the appstore?

I think that appstore is a great app-manager, but why was this app removed?

Comment: Note to those voting to close - this is not opinion based there is an exact definitive answer

Answer (score 3):

From [SourceTree's Blog](http://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/2013/05/07/sourcetree-for-mac-1-6/):

> **Mac App Store Note**
>
> A final note just to say that we no longer publish to the Mac App Store due to sandboxing restrictions. [Check Steve’s blog post about sandboxing for more information.](http://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/2012/06/29/mac-app-store-sandboxing-update/)